# Nginx: 301 Redirects from external file

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301

In Nginx, can 301 redirect URLs be grouped in an external file that can be included in the `.conf` file of the domain so that `.conf` is not modified each time a 301 redirect is needed?

Example:

A .nginx file, `.redirects` groups only 301 redirects:

```
location /test1 {
  rewrite ^ http://domain.com/test2 permanent;
}
```

Then, `.redirects` is included in the `.conf` file:

```
include /.redirects;
```

Can it work? (I've tested this and it didn't work for me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work but you need to mind one thing, what context is this file going to be included to.

In your condition it's a location block, so you need to include it inside a server block, not http for example,

Also use full path not relative

```
server {
  # bla bla
  include /etc/nginx/.redirects;
}
```